# What is the value stored in the memory space of a boolean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, boolean, language-lawyer

I don't know a great deal about memory space allotment. For every variable there will be a memory space allotted, so in the case of boolean variables in Python what value will be stored in the memory space of that variable?

Comment: Python abstracts memory management away, so don't worry about it! It has [names](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) rather than variables, too.

Comment: You can play around with `sys.getsizeof()` but as @jonrsharpe you shouldn't need to concern yourself with that, unless you have specific reason to

Comment: If you're *really* interested, though, look at [`boolobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/boolobject.c), which is the under-the-hood implementation of booleans for CPython.

Comment: `True is True` and therefore all `True` values may be the same object

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Technically, the definition of the per-`bool` structure is found in the [definition of a `PyLong`'s `struct _longobject`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/longintrepr.h) in Py3 (`PyLong` is the C name for an `int` in Py3), so `boolobject.c` doesn't actually describe the instance layout.

Comment: @ShadowRanger this is true!

Answer (score 3):

["Boolean values are the two constant objects False and True"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-boolean-values) i.e., `True is True` and `False is False` and it is true for any Python 3 program (for any implementation, not just CPython).

There are only two boolean objects, no matter how many names may refer to them in a Python program.

The size of an object may depend on implementation e.g., here's a result on my machine:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(True)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(False)
24
```

where [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) returns the size of object in bytes.

> in the case of boolean variables in Python what value will be stored in the memory space of that variable?

You could look at the memory on CPython:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> bytearray((ctypes.c_ubyte * sys.getsizeof(False)).from_address(id(False)))                            
bytearray(b'I\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@V\x9e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> bytearray((ctypes.c_ubyte * sys.getsizeof(True)).from_address(id(True)))
bytearray(b'9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@V\x9e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00')
```

Here are the corresponding [definitions in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d0e38b30b42b13559b009b19171889442598d004/Objects/boolobject.c#L174-L184). `bool` is an `int` subclass; here's [how `int` is represented in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d0e38b30b42b13559b009b19171889442598d004/Include/longintrepr.h#L11-L92).

Answer (score 2):

Note: The following description applies to the CPython reference interpreter for Python. The implementation details will vary in other interpreters, e.g. PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc.

Python's `bool` objects are singletons. So if you say:

```
a = True
b = bool('nonzerolen')
```

Then what you have is two references (named `a` and `b`) to the singleton instance of `True`; aside from the pointer used to hold each reference, no additional memory is allocated.

For the instance itself, as it happens, `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so the instance has the same layout as a Python `int` with a value of 0 or 1. The object itself differs slightly from Python 2 to Python 3, but it's basically the standard Python object header (including a reference to the class type and a reference count), plus a 0 or a 1 (as a signed `size_t` in Python 2, or a single element array of 16 or 32 bit values in Python 3).

Comment: if `a is b` then `a` and `b` are two names that refer to the same object. It does not depend on Python implementation.

Comment: Yeah, and since `bool`s are singletons in CPython, two names referencing `True` will always be the same `True` (and all references to `False` reference the same `False`).